# CSV - respresenting data in XLS

Tags: csv, xls, xlsx

I dump data into CSV format and later open with Microsoft Excel. I use CSV for saving RAM, using libraries like PHPExcel is not option due to big imprint on memory.

I'm happy with csv and would be even more if it were possible to split data into different columns.

Currently I use , as separator.

Is there some way to split data into columns?

[image]

Comment: excel's Data menu has a variety of tools for importing data from other sources. Use the Text option for importing CSVs (which also has options for importing files with non-standard colum delimiters).

Answer (score 0):

If saving RAM is a requirement that prevents you from using PHPExcel, then take a look at Spout: https://github.com/box/spout. You'll be able to export XLSX files super easily and without consuming too much memory.

Using CSV can lead to a lot of problems: encoding not respected, cell separators not correctly interpreted, etc... So I'd recommend you switching to XLSX instead!